# How to set the x-axis max with datetimes to the end of my data without knowing the value?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I am trying limit my x-axis on my plot with datetime. I only need to limit the xmin, not the xmax. I would like to plot from the datetime start that I indicate manually (2017, 1, 04, hour=13) to the end of the data that I have. Thus some of the data from the beginning will not appear on the plot. Unfortunately I don't always know the value of the datetime at the end of my data. I tried using `hour=:` but it does not work. Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here is my code:

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    x = [datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=2), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=14), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=15), datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=16)]
    y = [20, 12, 10, 14]

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=0.5, alpha=0.85)
    plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
    plt.ylabel("y value")
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlim(xmin=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=13), xmax=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 04, hour=:))

    plt.show()
```

This is what I am currently getting without the xlim:
[Figure_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGOfz.png)

This is what I would like to see:
[Figure_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXayL.png)

I saw on related questions where subplot was used:
    `ax = plt.subplots()`
 that the xmax could be get from
    `ax.get_xlim()`
but that does not work for me.

Comment: In `plt.xlim` you have `hour=:` at the end. Those are bad. Causes syntax error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to limit the x-axis so that it ranges from a static minimum to a dynamic maximum, with the max being the largest datetime object in your dataset, try

```
# ...
plt.xlim(
    xmin=datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 4, hour=13), # the one that doesn't change
    xmax=max(x) # the latest datetime in your dataset
)
```